# Javascript Pomodoro Timer - Pause/Play/General Functionality

Tags: javascript, timer, logic

so I seem to be having some real logic errors amidst my timer here, and I'm not quite sure how to fix them. I've made the code somewhat work, but I know for a fact there's a handful of logical errors, and I honestly have been working on it for a few days intermittently and can't seem to get it solved. Based on the code I've laid out you can pretty much understand my thinking of how I want to tackle this issue. I understand this isn't best practice, but I am just trying to work on my problem solving on these issues! Any help is greatly appreciated. I really need the most help on figuring out how to configure the Pause and Play functions with my given timer functionality. (Please no jQuery examples only raw JS)

```
// Necessary Variables for the program
let timer = document.querySelector(".time");
let button = document.querySelector("#btn");
let subtractBreak = document.querySelector("#subtractBreak");
let addBreak = document.querySelector("#addBreak");
let subtractSession = document.querySelector("#subtractSesssion");
let addSession= document.querySelector("#addSession");
// Keeping up with the current count of the break and session
let currentCount = document.getElementsByClassName("counterNum");
// Keeps up with all the buttons on session and break +/-
let counterBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("counterBtn");
// Pause and play Variables
let pause = document.querySelector("#pause");
let play = document.querySelector("#play");
// keeps up with an offsetting count.
let count = 0;
let timerGoing = false;
let sessionTimeLeft = 1500;
let breakTimeLeft = 5;
let timeWhilePaused = sessionTimeLeft;
let paused = false;

function formatTimer(time){
  let minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
  let seconds = time % 60;
  return `${minutes.toLocaleString(undefined, {minimumIntegerDigits: 2})}:${seconds.toLocaleString(undefined, {minimumIntegerDigits: 2})}`;
}


// This function needs to be fixed - It allows the timer to go negative past 0.
function countdown(){
  timerGoing = true;
    count++;
    timer.innerHTML = formatTimer(sessionTimeLeft - count);
    // Used to remove the listener
    button.removeEventListener("click", interval);
    console.log("Timer is at: " + formatTimer(sessionTimeLeft - count) + "\nCount is at: " + count +  "\nsessionTimeLeft = " + sessionTimeLeft);
    // Checking if the time of the current session is up
    if(count == sessionTimeLeft){
      timerGoing = false;
      alert("We're here stop...");
      startBreak(breakTimeLeft);
    }
}

button.addEventListener("click", interval);
function interval(e){
  setInterval(countdown, 1000);
  console.log("running");
  e.preventDefault();
}
/*
I look through the event listener to be sure to check and see if any of them have been hit
not just the first one, which is what it would check for.
*/
for(let i = 0; i < counterBtn.length; i++){
  counterBtn[i].addEventListener("click", changeCount);
}

/*
  This functions whole job is to see which button was clicked using the 'event target'
  Once found it can determine if the id is subtract - then it will subtract the next element
  founds' amount, due to the structure of the HTML this will always be the number following;
  this process works vice versa for the addition, with the number being the element before.
*/
function changeCount(e){
  let clickedButtonsId = e.target.id;
  if(timerGoing == false){
    if(clickedButtonsId === "subtractBreak"){
      let currentValue = e.target.nextElementSibling.innerText;
      if(currentValue != 1){
      currentValue--;
      e.target.nextElementSibling.innerText = currentValue;
      breakTimeLeft -= 1;
    }
    } else if(clickedButtonsId === "subtractSession"){
        let currentValue = e.target.nextElementSibling.innerText;
          if(currentValue != 1){
        currentValue--;
        e.target.nextElementSibling.innerText = currentValue;
        sessionTimeLeft = currentValue * 60;
        // Allows the timer to update in real time
        timer.innerHTML = formatTimer(sessionTimeLeft);
      }
    }
    else if(clickedButtonsId === "addBreak"){
        let currentValue = e.target.previousElementSibling.innerText;
        currentValue++;
        e.target.previousElementSibling.innerText = currentValue;
        breakTimeLeft += 1;
      }
      else{
        let currentValue = e.target.previousElementSibling.innerText;
        currentValue++;
        e.target.previousElementSibling.innerText = currentValue;
        sessionTimeLeft = currentValue * 60;
        // Allows the timer to update in real time
        timer.innerHTML = formatTimer(sessionTimeLeft);
      }
  }
}

/* These functions below are not working */
pause.addEventListener("click", pauseTimer);
function pauseTimer(){
  timeWhilePaused = sessionTimeLeft;
  button.removeEventListener("click", interval);
  console.log("calling pause"+paused+"\n");
  paused = true;
  console.log("paused after: " + paused);
}

play.addEventListener("click", playTimer);
function playTimer(){
  console.log("Paused = " + paused);
  if(paused == true){
    console.log("calling play");
    console.log("Paused = " + paused);
    sessionTimeLeft = timeWhilePaused;
    setInterval(countdown, 1000);
  }
}

function startBreak(time){
  console.log("Calling this function");
  timer.innerHTML = formatTimer(breakTimeLeft - count);
}
```

Comment: separate your concern from the browser and write test for your business logic.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean?